# Can one feature file be called in another feature file in cucumber

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress

Below is my cypress-cucumber project structure.

If I want to use steps from the Login.feature, Logout.feature inside the Home.feature  how to do that?

Basically I want to reuse login & log out in Home istead of rewrite them in again in Home
Here is the configuration:

```
{
  "stepDefinitions": [
    "cypress/e2e/step_definitions/*.js"    // use any step in any feature
  ]
}

Login.feature
Feature: Successful Login into the application  
   Background: 
       Given Launch he application
       Then  I enter Username "xxxx"
       Then  I enter Password "xxxx"   
       Then  I click on Login Button

Home.feature      
    Feature:  application - Home Page with Page Object Model with cypress cucumber BDD
    
      Background: 
            Given I am on  Login page
            Then  I enter Username "XXXX"
            Then  I enter Password "XXXXX"   
            Then  I click on Login Button 
    
            Scenario: Verify Home Page after Login
                Then  I am on Home Page
                Then  I log out

Logout.feature
Feature: Logout from the application
      Background: 
            Then  I Log Out
```

LogoutSteps.js

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

import { Given, When, Then } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import { Logout } from "../../Pages/LogoutPage"
const logout = new Logout()


Then("I log out", () => {
    logout.clickLogout()

})
```

HomeSteps.js

```
// <reference types="Cypress" />
    
    import { Given, When, Then } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
    import { Login } from "../../Pages/LoginPage"
    import { Home } from "../../Pages/HomePage"
    import { Logout } from "../../Pages/LogoutPage"
    const login = new Login()
    const home = new Home()
    const logout = new Logout()
    
    Then("I am on Home Page", () => {
        home.verifyHomePage() 
        home.searchfield() 
    
    })
```

[image]

Comment: What configuration do you have?

Comment: @ Soithongsuk @Otto see the above I have added my configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't given details of configuration, but this sounds like a case for [common step definitions](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/step-definitions.md#example-2-directory-with-common-step-definitions).

For example

```js
{
  "stepDefinitions": [
    "cypress/e2e/[filepath].js",                  // 1) steps by feature
    "cypress/e2e/common-step-definitions/*.js"    // 2) common to all
  ]
}
```

```js
/home/john.doe/my-project
└── cypress
    └── e2e
        ├── foo
        │   ├── a.feature
        │   └── a.js
        ├── bar
        │   ├── b.feature
        │   └── b.js
        └── common-step-definitions
            ├── 1.js
            └── 2.js
```

But since you have **a single folder** for steps, it depends on how you configured things.

If you used pattern #2, you should be able to reference any steps in any feature:

```js
{
  "stepDefinitions": [
    "cypress/e2e/step-definitions/*.js"    // use any step in any feature
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Soithongsuk, I have updated by moving the Step-Definition files in to to the respective folder i.e LoginStep.js into the Login Folder as a sub folder  under Step-Definitions Main Folder and then Login.feature, Logout.feature define them as a Background by doing this it's picking the Login & Logout in Home.feature , during the test execution though Login.feature have no actions which is good.I have updated the above code please check But i like the the 1st approach you have mentioned "cypress/e2e/common-step-definitions/*.js"    // 2) common to all .

Comment: @Soithongsuk,Could you please elaborate or give give example Login Steps write under Common.js how to call in other features?.Much appreciated your help.